# Can not add all the classes files from the JNI folder in Eclipse (JAVA, Windows 7)

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, java-native-interface

I have a classes directory "JNA" contains follwing .class files :

```
MClass.class
SClass$SC_PROC.class
SClass$S_PROC.class
SClass.class
```

and then I tried to add this directory in my current project :
Java Build Path -> Add external class folder -> class (JNA)folder path -> ok

After this eclipse only adds two .class files :

```
MClass.class
SClass.class
```

I tried to put all class files in a jar file and added external jar, still the result is same :(

Please tell me how to add those remaining .class files ?
Note :  as Eclipse could not add remaining two .class files eclipse is giving an error :

```
    The type SClass$SC_PROC.class cannot be
resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Comment: clean the project, remove the lib, close eclipse and try to add it again perhaps you must close it again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075343/java-project-in-eclipse-the-type-java-lang-object-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-ind

Comment: Is it possible that Windows does not like '$' in the class name?

Comment: I did what Zelldon said...no effect :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read lot in order to make it run but, nothing could help,

> (Somebody said it is the known bug in eclipse)

So I just,

1. ported all the code to `NetBeans IDE` (I am using version 8.0),
2. added all the required classes folders and jars to the `Libraries`
   folder
3. added `bin` folder containing all required `.dll` to `PATH`
   environmental variable

and yay... :) It worked...