# Java JNA load DLL

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jna

I have a problem when I try load a DLL like this:

```
String a = "C:\\Users\\ElteGps 022\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication1\\src\\lib\\EQ2008_Dll.dll";
        String strDllFileName = m_strUserPath + "\\res\\EQ2008_Dll.dll";
        String strEQ2008_Dll_Set_Path = m_strUserPath + "\\res\\EQ2008_Dll_Set.ini";
        m_DllLibrary = (DllLibrary) Native.loadLibrary(a,DllLibrary.class);
```

I see this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'C:\Users\ElteGps 022\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication1\src\lib\EQ2008_Dll.dll': Nie mo¿na odnaleæ okrelonego modu³
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:163)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:236)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:140)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:379)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:364)
    at javaapplication1.Fun.main(Fun.java:280)
```

I read and I did this:

- [Can not add all the classes files from the JNI folder in Eclipse (JAVA, Windows 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937206/can-not-add-all-the-classes-files-from-the-jni-folder-in-eclipse-java-windows)
- [giving 'java.library.path' in netbeans for .dll/.so files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714785/giving-java-library-path-in-netbeans-for-dll-so-files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [JNA javadoc](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Native.html)

> **Library Search Paths** 
>   A search for a given library will scan the following locations:
>
> 1. `jna.library.path` User-customizable path
> 2. `jna.platform.library.path` Platform-specific
>      paths
> 3. On OSX, `~/Library/Frameworks`, 
>      `/Library/Frameworks`, and 
>      `/System/Library/Frameworks` will be searched for a
>      framework  with a name corresponding to that requested.  Absolute
>      paths to frameworks  are also accepted, either ending at the framework
>      name (sans ".framework")  or the full path to the framework shared
>      library  (e.g. CoreServices.framework/CoreServices).
> 4. Context class loader classpath.  Deployed native libraries
>      may be  installed on the classpath under 
>      `${os-prefix}/LIBRARY_FILENAME`, where
>      `${os-prefix}`  is the OS/Arch prefix returned by `Platform.getNativeLibraryResourcePrefix()`.
>      If bundled in a jar file, the  resource will be extracted to
>      `jna.tmpdir` for loading, and  later removed (but only if
>      `jna.nounpack` is false or not set).
>
> You may
>   set the system property `jna.debug_load=true` to make  JNA
>   print the steps of its library search to the console.

Native.loadLibrary doesn't work with a full path, try instead [System.load](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#load(java.lang.String))
If you can't use that you could also specify the directory of the dll **before the loading** by setting the enviroment variable of java like this

```
System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "C:\\Users\\ElteGps 022\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication1\\src\\lib");
```

**But this is higly not recommended since it will works only on your computer**

Comment: When I do this : System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "C:\\Users\\ElteGps 022\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication1\\src\\lib");  I see this same result

Comment: And when I use System.load I see this : Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka you are loading a 32bit library on a 64bit jvm that's the problem, try to load the same library compiled for 64bit

Comment: I load o 32 bit i download a java 32 bit ant it work but when I use a  System.load I can't create object  m_DllLibrary  = System.load I don't know how I can do it

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka Retry to use Native.loadLibrary with the full path and tell me what happens

Comment: When I use a Native.load Libary I have this : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Directory separator should not appear in library name: C:\Users\ElteGps 022\workspace22\EQ2008_Dll_Java\res\EQ6003_Dll.dll
 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
 at com.eq2008.Fun.main(Fun.java:278)

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka try to move the dll in the windows folder and test with Native.loadLibrary only with the name of the dll

Comment: I've noticed that when I use windows, OpenGL32.dll is automatically loaded, probably off the classpath. How does java go about adding native libraries to the classpath, and is there some list of which ones are on the classpath?